# libssl Library not loaded when running psql on Mac OS

Tags: postgresql, macos, openssl, psql

I am getting the following when trying to run `psql` locally.

I erroneously executed a `brew install` and quit out, too late clearly. Now, i'm left with this:

```
psql --version
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.5/lib/libpq.5.10.dylib
  Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      psql --version
```

Is there a way to fix this without un-installing and re-installing Postgres locally?

Comment: Why do you not want to un-install and re-install?